# Applying background color for paragraphs having -ve text indent

Tags: html, css, vb6, webbrowser-control, background-color

In one of my html page i have paragraph tags like shown below.

```
<P style="MARGIN-LEFT: 0.5in; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #656565;TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in; TEXT-ALIGN: justify;" >my text here</P>
```

In vb6 web browser control we load these pages and highlight background colour according certain conditions. It was working properly for all text and html elements. but for paragraphs having TEXT-INDENT with -ve value it does not work properly and highlight will not be complete and it will not highlight starting .25 in of text. So how it can be highlighted? in below picture first one is the error case(with text-indent) and second one is without indent.
[image]

So now how to apply background color for those text even if text indent is specified?

Answer (score 2):

You cant do this in the way you may anticipate, but you can reduce the margin and add padding to the element by the amount relating to the indent value specified.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9dE6/1/)

```
<P style="MARGIN-LEFT: 0.25in; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #656565;TEXT-INDENT: -0.25in;padding:0 .25in; TEXT-ALIGN: justify;" >my text here<br />more text here</P>
```

Note that you should always try to use lowercase characters for your CSS, and favour using stylesheets instead of inline values.

HTML

```
<p>
   my text here
   <br />
   more text here
</p>
```

CSS

```
p {
    margin-left: 0.25in;
    background: #656565;
    text-indent: -0.25in;
    padding:0 .25in;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want `first-line` a bit wider than other, you may use an `absolute` tag or pseudo of `0.25in` `width` and average `1.2em` `height`.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/thoBd/)**

[image]

```
p{
  margin-left: 0.5in;
  background-color:#656565; 
  text-indent:-0.25in;
  text-align:justify; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
p:before {
  content:'';
  height:1.4em;/* average height of a line , to reset to match line-height if set on parent */
  width:0.25in;/* at least equal to negative indent */
  position:absolute;/* but no coordonates, let it follow text flow */
  z-index:-1;/* under text plz*/
  background-color:#656565; /* value can be inherit */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you can't do it to the `<p>` itself. You have to create a container for it and then do so. It is always best when you wrap elements inside divs. It's good site architecture practice.

Here is a [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbhmI/)

And here's the code

```
<div class="box">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.        </p>
</div>

.box{
    background-color:#656565;
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 0px;

 }
  p{
     margin-left: 0.5in; /* WHY INCHES? CAN YOU DO EM OR PX? */
     text-indent:-0.25in;
    text-align:justify; 
     box-sizing:border-box;
 }
```